# Trying to set up action_mailer with Sendgrid and heroku on Rails 5 API only app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, sendgrid

I'm trying to set up a Rails 5 API only app that receives a POST request with form data and emails that information to a specific email. I'm basically trying this to a contact form and trying to get rails to email that message to me.

I set up a Rails 5 API only app and got everything to work in local server. But when I deploy it to heroku, the app keeps crashing. Here's the logs:-

```
2017-10-21T12:31:49.779066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 28435 -e production`
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.419975+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.419961+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.419975+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.419976+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.419981+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Russell's Teapot
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.419982+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.419982+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.568829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.420126+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://******:28435
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.463851+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465644+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:270:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465656+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:270:in `new'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465664+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:105:in `block in parse'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465663+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:270:in `add_tcp_listener'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465665+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465665+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465666+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:144:in `load_and_bind'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/single.rb:87:in `run'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:183:in `run'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465668+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:69:in `run'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465669+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465679+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465680+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465680+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465681+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465681+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465682+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465683+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465687+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465686+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465687+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.465689+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    2017-10-21T12:31:53.582296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2017-10-21T12:32:04.663844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=****** request_id=ae664dd1-a48e-4033-9533-79464373cba8 fwd="157.50.15.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2017-10-21T12:32:06.597178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=****** request_id=48a773e2-e949-4820-b415-42a3071f79b9 fwd="157.50.15.44" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

There's this specific error " getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)" that I'm getting. I looked this up and found several sources suggesting to add 'require resolv-replace' in the initializers. I did and there's no change. The app keeps crashing.

I must mention that I copy pasted code from my working Rails 5 (non-API) application and adapted controller methods to render in JSON.

And as I mentioned, I got it to work in the local server, so it's got something to do with heroku and the sendgrid addon that I added via the command on the CLI.

Here's the code:-

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.valid?
        ContactMailer.contact(@message).deliver_now
        render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Message sent successfully!'}, status: :ok
    else
        render json: {status: 'ERROR', message: 'Message sending failed!', data: @message.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

  private

    def message_params
      params.permit(:subject, :name,
                                      :email, :content)
    end
end
```

Lines added to production.rb

```
   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    host = ENV['HOST']
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :port           => ENV['SMTP_PORT'],
      :address        => ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'],
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :domain         => 'heroku.com',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
```

The environment variables are added to heroku config variables via the settings page online.

Please let me know if any other information would be helpful.

Comment: Please can you share the values in your environment variables.

Comment: I struggled so much with that error that I just figured it was worth creating a new app. and redoing the changes. At every little change I checked to see if the app failed and it never did. I'm not sure what caused the issue, didn't look too keenly at it.